# Pass objects in a standardized way to interfaces/abstract classes

Tags: java, plugins, interface, annotations, abstract

**Background:** I often ask myself the following question and I never found an answer without flaws and I think this is a common problem in modularized software development. So I am not quite sure if programmers.stackexchange.com is more suitable - but this question is totally focused on Java and I want a Java solution:

**Example:** There is a text editor that loads several plugins who are responsible for their file type interaction in the text editor (Java plugin handles Java code/files, C/C++ plugin handles C/C++ code/files etc.) - each plugin needs a configuration and access to the file manager. These plugins have to access an application API to do some useful stuff without reinventing the wheel. Keep in mind, that for example the file manager of the application also needs data/objects itself (For example a configuration with line separator type, type of read mode etc.).

**Question:** How can I pass the configuration/file manager to an pugin (Based on an interface or abstract class) in a modularized application when the file manager also need a configuration itself?

**Problems/Things to keep in mind:**

- We need to pass data to the file manager (Configuration etc.)
- Java doesn't support custom constructors in interfaces and abstract classes
- Annotation'ed objects are hard to test and often the root of all evil
- Try to create a proper/clear API and make it hard as possible to abuse/use the API in a wring way

**Solution 1:** Use dependency injection via annotation in the plugins, so we can get the configuration and file manager and use them in our plugins. This is the smoothest solution but not that easy to test.

```
public class JavaPlugin implements Plugin
{
    @Autowired
    Configuration configuration;

    @Autowired
    FileManager filemanager;

    public String processText(String rawtext)
    {
        // Do stuff and access the configuration/file manager
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** Make the file manager a singleton ... but wait, how do we pass the configuration to the singleton? Make another static method that takes these parameters? That's not really a singleton anymore and the hell of a proper API.

```
public class JavaPlugin implements Plugin
{
    public String processText(String rawtext)
    {
        FileManager filemanager = FileManager.getInstance();
        Configuration configuiration = filemanager.getConfiguration();
        // Do stuff and use the configuration/file manager
    }
}

public class FileManager
{
    private static FileManager filemanager;

    private Configuration configuration;

    private FileManager(Configuration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public static FileManager getIntialInstance(Configuration configuration)
    {
        if(filemanager == null)
        {
            filemanager = new FileManager(configuration);
        }
        return filemanager;
    }

    public static FileManager getInstance()
    {
        return filemanager;
    }

    public Configuration getConfiguration()
    {
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

**Solution 3:** Just tell all plugin developers to implement a constructor that takes a configuration and a file manager as parameters (Because Java doesn't support custom constructors in an interface/abstract class). We create the plugin objects with reflection and pass the configuration and file manager to the constructor. But what happens if we need a third object?

```
public class JavaPlugin implements Plugin
{
    public(Configuration configuration, FileManager filemanager)
    {
        // Save them
    }

    public String processText(String rawtext)
    {
        FileManager filemanager = FileManager.getInstance();
        Configuration configuiration = filemanager.getConfiguration();
        // Do stuff and use the configuration/file manager
    }
}

public class PhpPlugin implements Plugin
{
    public PhpPlugin()
    {
        // Oh dear you just broke your plugin....
    }

    public String processText(String rawtext)
    {
        // Do stuff and use the configuration/file manager
    }
}
```

**Final thoughts:** I am not 100% satisfied with one of these 3 solutions - everyone has flaws. I prefer a puristic that forces a developer to follow the API (For example he should not be able to use a singleton anywhere - he should get the data and if he needs them he has to store them - otherwise he has to deal with it).

**StackOverflow question:** Are there other ways to "solve" this problem (Maybe thoughts I missed)?

Comment: Did I miss something or why didn't you mention simply using setters for the FileManager and the Configuration, which you can enforce via interfaces, autowire via Spring (or inject yourself, since you can simply test for the interface) AND mock for UnitTests.

Comment: That's another solution of course, but for me this isn't a proper API because someone could access the file manager object and set the configuration to null - et voila you have the fun

Comment: While that's true, I don't see the problem. Someone could also write a FileManager implementation that throws random exceptions and set it there, ok. But planing for people doing the most stupid things possible isn't the best way to think, imho. I alway s assume reasonable coders.

Comment: Sorry, thought you mean the file manager. That would be a good idee... thank your for the input

Comment: Switched from Autowired to setters a while back, since it makes it easier to put mocks in there, removing the need for Spring in the unit test itself.

Comment: `Java doesn't support custom constructors in ... abstract classes` that's not true, abstract classes can have custom constructors.

Comment: You should enforce bean like states. If you need to force some implementation of initialization, just make initPlugin(...) method in the interface that you will call.

Comment: I don't know about Spring DI but I'd guess it has similar (if not better) capabilities as CDI has and thus testing with injected resources isn't that hard. You'd basically just provide mock beans and let the container inject those (for CDI Apache Deltaspike provides several ways to support testing).

Comment: The point was not that Spring couldn't inject mocks (easy enough), but that I don't want Spring in my Unittest code without any real need, since it adds another layer of complexity and slows the whole thing down. So I removed Spring from the unit tests and used setters. In the integration tests, Spring is used, of course.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I was not precise enough: I mean a custom abstract constructor with parameters

Comment: @swaechter ok abstract constructors are not possible, yes, but I doubt you'd need them. Just provide a constructor that stores what's needed and provide an abstract initialization method if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the input from Florian Schaetz I ended up with this solution which I really like:

- Hide all required methods from the plugin developer
- No constructor in plugins that extend the base plugin class
- Easy to add new variables/methods
- Proper and clean API

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PluginLoader
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new PluginLoader();
    }

    public PluginLoader()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration("Processed text from plugin: ");
        FileManager filemanager = new FileManager(configuration);
        ArrayList<Plugin> plugins = new ArrayList<>();

        Plugin plugin1 = new JavaPlugin();
        plugin1.setConfiguration(configuration);
        plugin1.setFileManager(filemanager);
        plugins.add(plugin1);

        Plugin plugin2 = new PhpPlugin();
        plugin2.setConfiguration(configuration);
        plugin2.setFileManager(filemanager);
        plugins.add(plugin2);

        for(Plugin plugin : plugins)
        {
            System.out.println(plugin.getOutputName());
        }       
    }

    public class JavaPlugin extends Plugin
    {
        public String getOutputName()
        {
            return getFileManager().getConfiguration().getText() + "JavaPlugin";
        }
    }

    public class PhpPlugin extends Plugin
    {
        public String getOutputName()
        {
            return getFileManager().getConfiguration().getText() + "PhpPlugin";
        }
    }

    public abstract class Plugin
    {
        private Configuration configuration;

        private FileManager filemanager;

        public abstract String getOutputName();

        public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration)
        {
            if(this.configuration == null)
            {
                this.configuration = configuration;
            }
        }

        public void setFileManager(FileManager filemanager)
        {
            if(this.filemanager == null)
            {
                this.filemanager = filemanager;
            }
        }

        public Configuration getConfiguration()
        {
            return configuration;
        }

        public FileManager getFileManager()
        {
            return filemanager;
        }
    }

    public class FileManager
    {
        private final Configuration configuration;

        public FileManager(Configuration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        public Configuration getConfiguration()
        {
            return configuration;
        }
    }

    public class Configuration
    {
        private final String text;

        public Configuration(String text)
        {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText()
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done. Personally, I would have made Plugin an interface (easier to mock, etc.) and just offered a basic AbstractPlugin for the people who want it, but that't probably just a question of taste.